# Create Bargraph of values in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
set.seed(85)
a <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:3,5,rep=TRUE)))
```

And I want to create a bargraph of the values in the dataframe (i.e. shows how many 0s, 1s, 2s, and 3s there are in all).

However

```
hist(a)
```

gives me the error `'x' must be numeric` but `as.numeric(a)` gives me the error `(list) object can not be coerced to type 'double'`

How do I make a bargraph of the values in a dataframe? Also preferably, it should ignore N/A values.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To graph *"how many 0s, 1s, 2s, and 3s there are in all"* is to graph counts of those values. The appropriate type of graph is therefore a **barplot**, not a histogram.

```
barplot(table(unlist(a)))
```

[image]

If the data has changed to have all elements of `a` equal to one of the values, in this case `"2"`, be replaced by `NA`, the solution could be to coerce to factor setting the levels manually.

```
a[a == "2"] <- NA
a2 <- unlist(a)
a2 <- factor(a2, levels = min(a2, na.rm = TRUE):max(a2, na.rm = TRUE))
barplot(table(a2))
```

[image]

## `ggplot2`

Also, in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60532844/8245406) there is a `ggplot` solution that is not right. I have proposed a correction in a comment but I haven't got an answer yet and the proposed correction also works for this case without needing a coercion to factor.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(stack(a), aes(x = values)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This does indeed answer the question as I framed it. However, would you also know the solution if I wanted a histogram of the data? Suppose `a[a=="2"] <- NA` if I do a barplot I only have 0,1 & 3 on the axis (and no "2" with 0 occurrences)

Answer (score 0):

Histograms, and hence geom_histogram in ggplot2, is for continuous data. You need a barplot to visualise discrete data. In addition to barplot in graphics, you can use geom_bar in ggplot2. The ggplot2 syntax is:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(85)
a <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:3,5,rep=TRUE)))
ggplot(stack(a)) + geom_bar(aes(x=values))
```

Comment: I would upvote but the data is not what the OP posted. And one of the problems is that the data set `a` has 10 columns, not just one like yours. Could you edit the answer to include `ggplot(stack(a), aes(x = values)) + geom_bar()`?